# How to simplify a time off request approval workflow？

Tags: workflow, activiti

We are design a time off request approva workflow for our customer. The company has many layers, so the workflow has many nodes. Since anyone in the nodes can ask for a leave, the process can be started from any node. We are using activiti engine, is there any best practice to simplify the workflow, or we must make all possible workflow combinations?

Answer (score 0):

The Question is a bit Ambiguous. But as far as i understood, Creating workflow for each case will be messy. One Workaround would be to create all the Atomic Workflows(identify small pieces in you flow that are significant and most importantly re-usable) and wire them to a single Parent WorkFlow via a Message Start Event or Signal Start event or by some custom java code. These Workflows can be triggered based on some pre-defined variables which can tell Activiti Which one to trigger.